# If final image of object is forming at viewer's eye, where will viewer see that object?

Tags: geometric-optics, lenses

If an object is kept at centre of curvature of convex lens and a viewer is present at centre of curvature of other side then where will he see that object?
I think he will see the object at it's original position?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The object will not be seen as though it was in its position $C_1$.

The viewer will see an out of focus image of the object around position $C_2$ because an image of the object is being formed at a distance which is less than the least distance of distinct vision for the eye (about $25 \,\rm cm$) ie inside the near point of the eye.

To get an impression of what would be seen, move your eye very close to the screen on which you are reading my answer and you will see the text on the screen but out of focus.